# How can I target the syntactical parent when using the ampersand?

Tags: sass, css-selectors, libsass

I'm trying to remove some duplication in my scss selector.

```
.container {
  .operation {
    color: green;
  }
  .row.is-active &,
  .row:hover & {
    .operation {
      color: inherit;
    }
  }
}
```

I tried rewriting it like this:

```
.container {
  .operation {
    color: green;
  }
  .row & {
    &.is-active, &:hover {
      .operation {
        color: inherit;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, this causes `.is-active` to be applied to `.container` instead of `.row`

How can I target the syntactical parent when using the ampersand ?

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: @Mr_Green the expected output is the result of the first sass example ( which is a valid example )

Comment: @WillemD'Haeseleer Now that I understand your question, I have modified my answer below, hopefully it is of some help :)

Answer (score 0):

I took some time to answer the question again, as I mis-understood it initially. Unfortunately there is absolutely no way possible to do this in SASS at the moment. Even when trying to make use of the more advanced [SASS functions](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html) to manipulate selectors and strings it is not possible.

**There is some Good News**

It is possible to do using [Stylus](http://stylus-lang.com/).
I have created a live [Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eBNVxB/?editors=0100#0) on codepen.

```CSS
  // Stylus - not SASS
  .container {
    .operation {
      color: green;
    }
    .row {
      ^[-1..-1]:is-active ^[0], ^[-1..-1]:hover ^[0] {
        .operation {
          color: inherit;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I hope this helps you in some way, at the very least it might provide you with an option, but unfortunately SASS cannot achieve what you are attempting.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you mean. My first scss example is valid scss and as such the compiled output from that is the expected output. I'm just trying to write it without having to duplicate the .row selector

Comment: Ok, so i've re-looked over my result and the result from your first example, and they are different. I was after the CSS output to be able to confirm and test against it to be certain that it I can duplicate the result.

My result is different from the CSS output. without any further information I really can't help, sorry.

Comment: Thanks , I appreciate the effort, however in stylus the proposed solution is more complex then the original solution, which kind off defies the purpose.